# mmap() and pthreads - copy VMA

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pthreads, mmap

I `mmap()` an anonymous VMA. How do pthreads handle that VMA?
I want that the vma with its memory is copied for every thread. Which flags do I need for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mmap() an anonymous VMA. How do pthreads handle that VMA?

"pthreads" (user-space library for threads in Linux) have no special handling of new VMA's from mmap.

> I want that the vma with its memory is copied for every thread.

You can't, because every thread of single process have the same VMA.

Default pthread implementation in glibc - the NPTL, uses `clone` syscall with `CLONE_VM` flag:
http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/createthread.c

```
47 static int
48 create_thread (struct pthread *pd, const struct pthread_attr *attr,
49         bool stopped_start, STACK_VARIABLES_PARMS, bool *thread_ran)
50 {
66  /* We rely heavily on various flags the CLONE function understands:
67
68     CLONE_VM, CLONE_FS, CLONE_FILES
69  These flags select semantics with shared address space and
70  file descriptors according to what POSIX requires.

94  const int clone_flags = (CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SYSVSEM
95             | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_THREAD
96             | CLONE_SETTLS | CLONE_PARENT_SETTID
97             | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID
98             | 0);
99

102  if (__glibc_unlikely (ARCH_CLONE (&start_thread, STACK_VARIABLES_ARGS,
103                 clone_flags, pd, &pd->tid, tp, &pd->tid)
```

And [man page of clone](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) says:

```
   CLONE_VM (since Linux 2.0)
          If CLONE_VM is set, the calling process and the child process
          run in the same memory space.  In particular, memory writes
          performed by the calling process or by the child process are
          also visible in the other process.  Moreover, any memory
          mapping or unmapping performed with mmap(2) or munmap(2) by
          the child or calling process also affects the other process.
```

So, *any memory mapping or unmapping performed with mmap(2) or munmap(2) by* one thread is seen by all threads of process in linux glibc pthreads. There is no need for additional flag to mmap; CLONE_VM flag is already given to clone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a pitty, I thought there is a flag which would copy the memory. Just like the stack which is copied, too.

Comment: You need no copy memory between threads; they all have common memory space. There is MMAP_SHARED to memory be shared between different processes...

Comment: @tobawo: The stack isn't copied either - a new stack (at a new virtual address) is created for each new pthread.

Comment: "...user-space library for threads in Linux...". pthread API is not a Linux specific interface, rather, many POSIX compliant operating systems have pthread API available. POSIX threads is a standard API defined by POSIX.1c

Comment: @FehmiNoyanISI, The question is about linux (linux-kernel), and glibcs libpthread (nptl) is the linux implementation of something something. It uses linux-specific clone syscall. POSIX thread api may be implemented in other way in other oses, but the linux api/abi is most popular one. And there is almost no other alive implementation of POSIX threads for linux.